# want to match multiple conditions in lookup operation in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

i want to do is lookup for two foreign fields `from` and `to` in chat document to match with two user `_id`'s that are sender-id and receiver-id.

```
user collection :[{
    _id: { $oid: "64428badffd445ba3c11a9b4" },
    firstName: "test",
    lastName: "user",
    type: { $numberInt: "2" },
    email: "test@user.com",
    password: "$2a$10$gm25OtxxAGl3Cj4V.ZoQ0OngID0eAfaAdQh5sQeKJ0aTyoVukChkG",
    createdAt: { $date: { $numberLong: "1682082733141" } },
    updatedAt: { $date: { $numberLong: "1682082733141" } },
    __v: { $numberInt: "0" },
  }]


chats collection : [{
    _id: { $oid: "644f892004492f9c01296861" },
    from: { $oid: "64428badffd445ba3c11a9b4" },
    to: { $oid: "644a07431babb4a2df531f2a" },
    message: "hello",
    createdAt: { $date: { $numberLong: "1682934048968" } },
    updatedAt: { $date: { $numberLong: "1682934048968" } },
    __v: { $numberInt: "0" },
  }]
```

So how can i access current user `_id` in following lookup operation

```
const recentChats = await User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "chats",
        as: "chatHistory",
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [{ from: req.params.id }, { to: "$$id" }],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ]);
```

i want to get current user `_id` (on which the `chatHistory` field will be added)

I have tried this

```
const recentChats = await User.aggregate([
    {
      $lookup: {
        from: "chats",
        as: "chatHistory",
        let: {
          vars: { id: { $getField: "_id" } },
        },
        pipeline: [
          {
            $match: {
              $or: [{ from: req.params.id }, { to: "$$id" }],
            },
          },
        ],
      },
    },
  ]);
```